# How do I add an Icon to an Iconless exe file?

Tags: windows, icons, exe

I made my own exe file for a game i made, But the exe file has no Icon and I cant find a way to change it.

Resource hacker isnt working because it didnt have an Icon in the first place.

Any solution?

Answer (score 5):

In Resource hacker when you have your icon-less exe open.  
[image][image: you can name the rea], goto the action tab and click 'Add an Image or Other Binary Resource...' it will open a small window labeled 'Add Binary Resource'. click the select file button. Select your .ico file and press open, then you can name the icon resource to your choosing. Afterwards press 'Add Resource' this will add an icon to your exe file. [image]Finally press save to Save the exe.[image]

Answer (score -1):

If Your Application Was Made Out of Window.h file in C++ Language You can Do,
While Registering the Class with the WNDCLASS theres an Variable hicon, You can Just the Add the Icon there it also has another variable field hicomsm you can add the icon even there.
This Page Here has the Full Reference to it
-> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassa

Comment: That doesn't associate an icon with the executable file.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-assign-a-custom-icon-to-a-file-type

Comment: I Guess This Helps You

Comment: No, it does not. The resource shows how to associate icons with file extensions. This does not associate an icon with an executable file.